# How to define the title link of a Google Gadget?

Tags: title, google-gadget

I am designing a simple Google Gadget, and I would like the Gadget title to be a link (like the GMail gadget where the title link points toward the originating GMail app).

Does anyone know how to achieve such a behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution at http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/ui.html#Settitle The catch is not to forget to include the line `<Require feature="settitle"/>` among module preferences.